# Should I create an empty string and append through a foreach loop or should I use StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, .net, strings

Here's the current code:

```
    static string GetResources(string header, string filter, string resourceTemplate)
    {
        string themeName;
        if (!TryGetHeaderValue(header, "theme", out themeName)) return "";

        var resources = "";
        var path = Path.Combine(HtmlPreview.BaseDirectory, themeName);

        foreach (var resource in Directory.GetFiles(path, filter))
        {
            resources += String.Format(
                resourceTemplate,
                themeName,
                Path.GetFileName(resource));
        }

        return resources;
    }
```

I was wondering if I should use string builder instead:

```
static string GetResources(string header, string filter, string resourceTemplate)
    {
        string themeName;
        if (!TryGetHeaderValue(header, "theme", out themeName)) return "";

        var resourcesStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var path = Path.Combine(HtmlPreview.BaseDirectory, themeName);

        foreach (var resource in Directory.GetFiles(path, filter))
        {
            resourcesStringBuilder.Append(String.Format(
                resourceTemplate,
                themeName,
                Path.GetFileName(resource)));
        }

        return resourcesStringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Resharper simply suggests it is possible to replace the original code with a LINQ statement:

```
    static string GetResources(string header, string filter, string resourceTemplate)
    {
        string themeName;
        if (!TryGetHeaderValue(header, "theme", out themeName)) return "";

        var path = Path.Combine(HtmlPreview.BaseDirectory, themeName);

        return Directory.GetFiles(path, filter)
            .Aggregate("", 
            (current, resource) => current + 
                String.Format(resourceTemplate, 
                themeName, 
                Path.GetFileName(resource)));
    }
```

Thank you! The original code with context is also on [github](https://github.com/kusl/DownmarkerWPF/blob/master/src/MarkPad/Document/DocumentParser.cs#L117).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about understanding the fundamentals of the framework, not a code review.

Answer (score 7):

Strings in C# are immutable which means that this:

```
 resouces += string.Format(...);
```

will create 2 strings: one from `string.Format` and then the new string created by appending it to the existing string.

A `StringBuilder` will just keep a list of all the strings to append and create one result string at the end when you call `ToString()`. So instead of `2*n` strings you only create `n+1` strings. The `Aggregate` has the same problem.

There are some optimizations in the C# compiler which can transform `string + string + string + ...` sequences into `Append` calls on a `StringBuilder` but you should not really rely on this.

In the end it doesn't matter too much if your strings a short. However when you hit the 85kb limit then the strings will be placed on the large object heap which can cause problems because it doesn't get compacted and you can get holes. This can lead to weird out of memory situations (you can find more with google).

Comment: Thank you. These are local file paths so I doubt we'd hit the 85kb limit here but that is really good to know.

Answer (score 5):

Using `string +=` in a loop is a very severe code smell, the worst possible solution both in terms of performance and memory fragmentation. Never do that, the `StringBuilder` class is designed exactly for such scenarios.

**Edit**
The reason in short is that string concatenation with `+=` will result in reallocation of the entire string for each loop cycle, whereas a `StringBuilder` is using a preallocated buffer which is filled with the individual parts.

Comment: this sounds like the start to a very good answer,  I am tempted to upvote it, as is, but I think you should elaborate a little bit more on why it is a code smell and how `StringBuilder` is designed to handle this situation.

Comment: @Malachi Here you go...